# Bijection between dominant rational maps and morphisms of function fields?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two integral schemes of finite type over a field $k$. Consider the function fields $K(X)$ and $K(Y)$.

Do we have a bijection between:

(a) Dominant rational maps $X \rightarrow Y$

(b) $k$-algebra morphisms $K(Y)$ to $K(X)$.

This kind of result is stated at several places in the literature. But I am surprised to see that the varieties are always taken to be affine, quasi-affine, quasi-projective etc (Hartshorne does this for instance)

Does the result not hold in general when $X$ and $Y$ are just schemes of finite type? I would really appreciate a reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably always possible to reduce to the affine case: rational maps are only defined up to restricting to a dense open subset.

A possible reference is (the amazing) "Foundations of algebraic geometry":
 http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGdec3014public.pdf
See for instance Proposition 6.5.7 p190 and the exercise 6.5.D p191.

(this should be a comment, but I am not allowed to comment yet)